# Receiving NA while using as.date

Tags: r

I have a a column docDate - character class and want to convert to date class:

```
class(df$docDate)

[1] "character"

head(df$docDate)

[1] "2014-08-13" "2014-08-13" "2014-08-12" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
```

But, when I convert with this function, nothing is converted, instead it is replaced by NAs/

```
 df$docDate <- as.Date(df$docDate,format = "%m/%d/%y")

 head(df$docDate)

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What can be a reason?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing an incorrect format. `docDate` is in year, month, day order, but you are giving it month, day , year in addition to having the wrong separator `/`, instead of `-`.

```
df$docDate <- as.Date(df$docDate,format = "%Y-%m-%d")

#[1] "2014-08-13" "2014-08-13" "2014-08-12" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-02-01"
```

However, your date is already in the format that `as.Date` expects, so you can just skip adding the format.

```
df$docDate <- as.Date(df$docDate)
```